# Prove covergence of ${a_{n}}$given convergence of $b_{n}=p*a_{n}+q*a_{n+1}$

Tags: analysis

Let ${a_{n}}$ be a sequence such that the sequence $b_{n}=p*a_{n}+q*a_{n+1}$, where $|p|<q$, is convergent. Prove that ${a_{n}}$ is convergent. If $|p|\ge q>0$ show that ${a_{n}}$ need not converge.

Comment: Look at $a_n= (-1)^np^n/q^n$.

Comment: I see that converges but how did you get it?

Comment: No, I meant that for the second part, as an example where it diverges, but $b_n=0$.

Comment: Shift the sequences $B_n=b_n-\ell$ and $A_n=a_n-\frac{\ell}{p+q}$ so that $B_n\to 0$ and it is easier to show that $A_{n+1}\sim \frac pq A_n$ leading to geometric growth.

Comment: Hint: we have $b_{n+1} = p a_{n+1} + q a_{n+2}$ and $b_n = p a_n + q a_{n+1}$.  Subtracting, we can conclude $p (a_{n+1} - a_n) + q (a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have $|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \le \frac{|p|}{q} (|a_{n+1} - a_n| + \epsilon)$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Use this to show that the sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.